# Primary expression C++ error

Tags: c++

I have to write some programs for a class final and I'm running into an error that I can't figure out.  I have checked the syntax in this program many times and it isn't very long so I don't know why I can't find it.  When I try and compile, I get an error that says "expected primary-expression before '}' token".  It says it's in line 23.  Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sumOfPrimes = 2;

    for (int x=3; x<2000000; x++)
    {
        for (int y=2; y<x; y++)
        {
            if (x % y == 0)
            {
                goto break1;
            }
        }
        sumOfPrimes += x;
        break1:
    }

    cout << sumOfPrimes << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a *statement* after a label. The null statement `;` works fine:

```
break1: ;
```

Comment: That did it.  I knew it was going to be something small and silly.  Thanks!